# Trying to reloadData() in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a tabBarController and in one of the tabs I can select whatever document to be in my Favourites tab.

So when I go to the Favourites tab, the favourite documents should appear.

I call the reloading after fetching from CoreData the favourite documents:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    languageSelected = UserDefaults().string(forKey: "language")!

    self.title = "favourites".localized(lang: languageSelected)

    // Sets the search Bar in the navigationBar.
    let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    search.searchResultsUpdater = self
    search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    search.searchBar.placeholder = "searchDocuments".localized(lang: languageSelected)
    navigationItem.searchController = search
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

    // Request the documents and reload the tableView.
    fetchDocuments()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

The fetchDocuments() function is as follows:

```
func fetchDocuments() {
    print("fetchDocuments")
    // We make the request to the context to get the documents we want.

    do {

        documentArray = try context.fetchMOs(requestedEntity, sortBy: requestedSortBy, predicate: requestedPredicate)
        ***print(documentArray) // To test it works ok.***
        // Arrange the documentArray per year using the variable documentArrayPerSection.
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"

        for yearSection in IndexSections.sharedInstance.allSections[0].sections {

            let documentsFilteredPerYear = documentArray.filter { document -> Bool in
                return yearSection == formatter.string(from: document.date!)
            }

            documentArrayPerSection.append(documentsFilteredPerYear)

        }

    } catch {

        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")

    }

}
```

From the statement print(documentArray) I see that the function updates the content. However there is no reload of documents in the tableView.

If I close the app and open it again, then it updates.

Don't know what am I doing wrong!!!

Comment: Only thing I can think of being the problem is that `fetchMOs` is executed on a background thread so the `tableView.reloadData()` happens before the `documentArray` gets updated. Is that the case?

Comment: It is not the case. This is the function:     func fetchMOs (_ entityName: String, sortBy: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws -> [Document] {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        request.predicate = predicate
        request.sortDescriptors = sortBy
        return try! self.fetch(request) as! [Document]}

Comment: does `documentArrayPerSection` ever get cleared? Aren't you always appending to it when you switch tabs?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you move `tableView.reloadData()` into `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @TomPearson you were right!!!!!!!! It was a problem of cleaning documentArrayPerSection!!!!!!!!

Comment: @jRuMoL cool I'll add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're always appending to `documentArrayPerSection` but never clearing it so I imagine the array was always getting bigger but only the start of the array which the data source of the tableView was requesting was being used. Been there myself a few times.

Comment: @jRuMoL happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `reloadData()` is called before all data processing is done. To fix this you will have to call completion handler when fetching is done and only then update tableView.

```
func fetchDocuments(_ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
   do {
      // Execute all the usual fetching logic
      ...

      completion()
   }
   catch { ... }
}
```

And call it like that:

```
fetchDocuments() {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

---

Good luck :)